# String is there, but not printed

Tags: c, gcc, stack, printf

I have quite interesting problem, I guess. I am trying to implement Stack in C. Here is my header and implementation file(I have only implemented Push yet):

my.h:

```
typedef struct {
    char type[3];
    int nrOfOpr;
    int num;
} BizarreNumber_t;

struct stackNode {
    BizarreNumber_t data;
    struct stackNode *nextPtr;
};

// stack related
extern void push(struct stackNode *topPtr, BizarreNumber_t info);
```

my.c:

```
void push(struct stackNode *topPtr, BizarreNumber_t info){
    struct stackNode *newTop = malloc(sizeof(struct stackNode));
    struct stackNode oldTop = *topPtr;
    newTop->data=info;
    newTop->nextPtr=&oldTop;
    *topPtr=*newTop;
// printf("topPtr->next->data: %s\n", topPtr->nextPtr->data.type);
//
// printf("oldTop->data: %s\n", oldTop.data.type);
// printf("newTop->data: %s\n", newTop->data.type);
// printf("topPtr->data: %s\n", topPtr->data.type);
}
```

Lastly This is my main.c:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    struct stackNode* stackHead=malloc(sizeof(struct stackNode));

    BizarreNumber_t a={"sa",1,1};
    BizarreNumber_t b={"as",2,2};

    stackHead->data=a;
    stackHead->nextPtr=NULL;

    printf("%s\n", stackHead->data.type);
    push(stackHead,b);

    printf("%s\n", stackHead->nextPtr->data.type);//HERE!!!
    return 0;
}
```

In main, the line that I wrote "HERE!!!" is not correctly giving true output. Actually it does not give anything. Interesting thing is, whis gives correct output:

```
printf("%c\n", stackHead->nextPtr->data.type[0]);
```

I tried to print out every character in string, Results say that String comes main fine. But I cannot see. Why is it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stackHead` is local variable created in `main()` function. Whatever modification or changes done with `stackHead` in `push()` method won't affect in `main()` method as it just call by value.

Instead of this pass the address of `stackHead` to `push()` method as

```
push(&stackHead,b); /* pass the address of stackhead */
```

And change the definition of `push()` accordingly.

```
 void push(struct stackNode **topPtr, BizarreNumber_t info){
        struct stackNode *newTop = malloc(sizeof(struct stackNode));
        newTop->data = info;
        newTop->nextPtr = *topPtr; /*new node next make it to head node */
        *topPtr=newTop; /*update the head node */
 }
```

Comment: This did not affect. I am already sending a pointer, I tried your way though, It is still doesnt show up.
I want to remain that string can be seen by: printf("%c", str[0]);

Comment: Yes it should be "sa"

Comment: I am using gcc compiler in Linux Mint. Here is my 'gcc -v' : 'gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) '

Comment: @H.Durmaz compiler is not the issue for that. I modified my answer. check it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It's working fine now! But can I ask that, was it working for you at first? I mean My code should have worked because I am sending pointers too? Not pointer to pointer but pointer itself?